# How do I rewrite the following SQL code in Pandas to display the query and not just the headers?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have a dataset and I am trying to write SQL query into Pandas.

The SQL query code is:

```
`SELECT Industry_type, No_of_Employees, Employee_Insurance_Premium, Percent_Female_Employees FROM cdc_new
WHERE Industry_type= 'Hospitals' AND Employee_Insurance_Premium='Decreased'
ORDER BY Percent_Female_Employees DESC;`
```

This is the code that I wrote in Pandas:

```
pd.DataFrame(cdc_new[(cdc_new.Industry_type == 'Hospitals') & (cdc_new.Employee_Insurance_Premium == 'Decreased')][['No_of_Employees', 'Industry_type', 'Employee_Insurance_Premium', 'Percent_Female_Employees']].sort_values(['Percent_Female_Employees'], ascending=[False]))
```

and I get an output with ONLY the headers and no text.

Comment: Cab you share some dummy or sample table rows?

Comment: @bluepanther9999 kindly accept a solution by clicking the checkmark next to the solution if someone has answered your question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add the output/error that you received after running the second line? Can you add the line you used to create the `cdc_new` variable?

Did you already create a variable `cdc_new`? Try running:

`cdc_new.head()`

to see if your data matches the table you are querying.

If so, you should be able to run:

```
cdc_new[(cdc_new.Industry_type=='Hospitals') & (cdc_new.Employee_Insurance_Premium=='Decreased')]
```

The remainder of your code looked good. You don't need to wrap it in `pd.DataFrame()` as the data stored in `cdc_new` should already be a `DataFrame`.

If you are having an issue, double check that you get an output when running your SQL query and the data in the `cdc_new` variable matches the data table.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have read in the entire table from sql with something like:

```
cdc_new = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
```

You can use the following syntax:

```
df = (cdc_new.loc[(cdc_new['Industry_type'] == 'Hospitals') &
                  (cdc_new['Employee_Insurance_Premium'] == 'Decreased'),
                  ['Industry_type',
                   'No_of_Employees',
                   'Employee_Insurance_Premium',
                   'Percent_Female_Employees']]
             .sort_values('Percent_Female_Employees', ascending=False))
df
```

Answer (score -1):

If this works and returns records:

```
SELECT Industry_type, No_of_Employees, Employee_Insurance_Premium, Percent_Female_Employees FROM cdc_new WHERE Industry_type= 'Hospitals' AND Employee_Insurance_Premium='Decreased' ORDER BY Percent_Female_Employees DESC;
```

The record set is already trimmed and sorted, so you should use it as written. Use pandas for presentation here, not analysis.

Then use:

```
import pandas as pd 
cxn   = "Connection string to your database"

inSQL = "SELECT Industry_type, No_of_Employees, Employee_Insurance_Premium, Percent_Female_Employees FROM cdc_new WHERE Industry_type= 'Hospitals' AND Employee_Insurance_Premium='Decreased' ORDER BY Percent_Female_Employees DESC;"

df            = pd.read_sql(inSQL,cxn)
```